# Creating and writing large file to disk with a web app

Tags: javascript, gwt, web-applications

We have a web site that lets users create an animated sequence of sorts, which is then compiled into an object and made available for download. The problem is the file can get pretty large (500MB+) and browsers on lighter machines will understandably crap out as the file is getting built.

Is there a mechanism that lets us "stream" data into a file on the user's disk so we don't have to keep the whole compiled animation in memory?

We're using GWT as part of our technology stack. Ideally we do not push anything back to the web server (we want to support the use case where they may get disconnected from the internet while compiling the animation). There's some headway available to optimize the data but we'd rather have the most scalable solution possible.